# Rails Assets and CDN Issues (CSS, JS references)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, assets

I am dealing with Rails 3.1.2, asset_sync and cludfront. I have installed asset_sync and precompiled all the assets. The problem I am facing is the following:
rake compiles combine javascript and css files into a application.[js|css].
In production mode the application is still referencing the original name but with the new cdn path and I get a 404 error.

this is production env file:

```
Griov4::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to Rails.root.join("public/assets")
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = SyslogLogger.new

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  config.action_controller.asset_host = "#{ENV['CDN']}"

end
```

This is my .env file

```
FOG_PROVIDER=AWS
FOG_DIRECTORY=
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID= 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
CDN=http://d3tf1w68p27174.cloudfront.net
RACK_ENV=production
```

my manifest file within js folder:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//


//= require_tree .
```

my manifest file within css folder:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll automatically include all the stylesheets available in this directory
 * and any sub-directories. You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at
 * the top of the compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap.min
*/
```

Then I type: `$`bundle exec rake assets:clean assets:precompile

application.ss and application.js gets created but unfortunately the production application still refers to the original css/js files with the following path:

http://d3tf1w68p27174.cloudfront.net/assets/home-24d72d1643e0016381b14c19d90d9e74.css

http://d3tf1w68p27174.cloudfront.net/assets/home-74ac0007a6e42997f8210f80b99a203b.js

I checked both my local folder and the cdn folder and none of them contains those files.
asset_sync is working correctly because I can see the rest of the assets on my cdn folder.

I know it could be something related to the asset pipeline, but I can't figure out what it is.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

To ensure all of your assets reference the new asset host, make sure you’re using the Rails `AssetTagHelper` methods (like `image_tag`, `stylesheet_link_tag`, `favicon_link_tag`, etc).

If you are using background image references in your CSS, you can leverage the [multiple asset-preprocessor](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#preprocessing) support to ensure they also reference the new asset host.

For example, to enable multiple asset-preprocessing on "home.css", you can add the `.erb` extension to it changing it to "home.css.erb". This file will first be processed by ERB, then CSS, which means you can reference your assets as shown in the example below:

```
body {
    background: url(<%= asset_path 'bg.png' %>);
}
```

You can take this further by doing something like "home.css.scss.erb".

See [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb) and [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31#asset-references-in-css--js) for more info.